# I think I'm confusing name hiding with function overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm confused...it seems that both things do the same thing.

In this first code, I believe that the derived classes are hiding the function names of the base classes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Quadrilateral {

public:
   void greeting() {
       std::cout << "i am a quadrilateral" << std::endl;
   }
};

class Square : public Quadrilateral {
 public:
    void greeting() {
        std::cout << "i am a square" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Trapezoid : public Quadrilateral {

public:
    void greeting() {   //hides greeting from quadrilateral function
        std::cout << "Hi I'm a Trapezoid" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Trapezoid tz;
    tz.greeting();  
}
```

This seems to have the same exact result: [here they are being overriden because it is virtual in the base class]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Quadrilateral {

public:

    virtual void greeting() {
        std::cout << "i am a quadrilateral" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Square : public Quadrilateral {
  public:
    void greeting() {
        std::cout << "i am a square" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Trapezoid : public Quadrilateral {

public:
    void greeting() {   //hides greeting from quadrilateral function
        std::cout << "Hi I'm a Trapezoid" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Trapezoid tz;
    tz.greeting();  
}
```

So I guess I'm just really confused as to...what is the difference? Or what is the point of making it virtual in the base class if it's just gonna have the same effect in this situation?

Comment: The second doesn't hide it, but overrides it.

Comment: I know, but it seems to do the same thing whether you override it or hide it. So what's the point? @LuchianGrigore

Comment: Try this in both cases: Make an instance of the derived class. Make a pointer to it with the type of the base class. Call the function on the base class pointer (which actually points to an instance of the derived class).

Comment: @Navin You don't have to. It's just so the compiler will actually tell you if you get it wrong.

Comment: Note: `Square::greeting()` genuinely hides `Quadrilateral::greeting()` by overriding as `private` in the first set, (which I'm not entirely sure you did intentionally). Edit: look at that, fully interactive hands-off code-editing.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual functions are used to call the overriden function from the base class pointer.
With your second example you can get the same result if you do the following in the `main()`

```
 Trapezoid tz;
 Quadrilateral *base = &tz;
 base->greeting(); // it will print "Hi I'm a Trapezoid"
```

And this is the difference with the first example: possibility to call derived function from the base class pointer.
If you not override the virtual base function in the derived class, then the base virtual function will be called.

**Usage example.**

Imagine, that you want to create many objects with the base class `Quadrilateral` (for example five squares and three trapezoids):

```
Square sq1, sq2, sq3, sq4, sq5;
Trapezoid tz1, tz2, tz3;
```

Now, at some point in your code you want to go throw all of this objects and call the abstract function (in your case `greeting()`). So, with help of virtual function you can do it very simple: put all objects in an array of pointers and call the propper function. Here is how:

```
Quadrilateral *base[8] = {&sq1, &sq2, &sq3, &sq4, &sq5, &tz1, &tz2, &tz3};
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    base[i]->greeting();
}
```

In the output you will recieve five times `"i am a square"` and three times `"Hi I'm a Trapezoid"`.
It comes vary helpfully when you create all different shapes (for example with different dimensions, properties) and want to go throw all of this objects and call, for example, `calc()` function to make an calculation individualy for each shape.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if you declare/have a struct or class variable like in this example, the compiler trivially knows its type and always calls the correct function, irrespective of virtual/not.

Virtual functions only matter when dealing with pointers or references.

Try adding this after you existing code, before the end of main:

```
Quadrliateral *q = &t;
q->greeting();
```

And you will find it matters a lot whether all the greetings functions are virtual or not.

Comment: Okay. True, I should have known this. However, I'm still kinda confused as to what exactly is the benefit of being able to use a derived type object by having a base type pointer to it? Like..what do I get out of that? The only thing I notice different is that if the derived class has a function not defined in the base class, and you make a base* pointer to the derived class object, then the derived class' functions that were not in the base class are no longer accessible. What benefit does that give me? @RichardPlunkett

Comment: I guess sometimes you want a pointer to any quadrilateral, but don't care if it is a square or a trapezoid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, format your code please!

**First example**

```
class Quadrilateral {
  public:
    void greeting() {
      std::cout << "i am a quadrilateral" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Square : public Quadrilateral {
  void greeting() {
    std::cout << "i am a square" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Trapezoid : public Quadrilateral {
  public:
    void greeting() {   //hides greeting from quadrilateral function
      std::cout << "Hi I'm a Trapezoid" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  Trapezoid tz;
  tz.greeting();  
}
```

In this example is totally normal that Trapezoid.greeting() hides Quadrilateral.greeting(): it's an overriding (same method name, same return, same parameters (none)).

**Second example**

```
class Quadrilateral {
  public:
   virtual void greeting() {
     std::cout << "i am a quadrilateral" << std::endl;
   }
};

class Square : public Quadrilateral {
  void greeting() {
    std::cout << "i am a square" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Trapezoid : public Quadrilateral {
 public:
  void greeting() {   //hides greeting from quadrilateral function
    std::cout << "Hi I'm a Trapezoid" << std::endl;
  } 
 };

int main() {
  Trapezoid tz;
  tz.greeting();  
}
```

The same. You create an objcet of static-type Trapezoid that have dynamic-type Trapezoid. So tz.greeting will print "I'm a trapezoid" because greeting() is an override.

**Third example**

```
class Shape {
  public:
    virtual void greeting() {
      std::cout << "Shape" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Square : public Shape {
  /* override method greeting() of Shape class */
  void greeting() {
    std::cout << "Square" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
  public:
  /* override method greeting() of Shape class */
    void greeting() {   
      std::cout << "Triangle" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  Shape* shape = new Triangle();
  shape->greeting(); /* prints "Triangle" */
  shape = new Square();
  shape->greeting(); /* prints "Square" */
}
```